# Most efficient way to count number of overlapping occurrences

Tags: java

How do I count the number of **overlapping** occurences in a string efficiently?

For example, `count('XLXXXLXX','XX')` should return `3`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show us your code, please?

Comment: You need to be more clear with your question. Does your method always take two arguments? Does overlapping mean even partial match among strings?

Comment: @SunilDabburi The requirement is pretty clear. Overlapping means two found matches can overlap, nothing about partial matches. So `'XXX'` contains two overlapping occurrences of the substring `'XX'`.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use `indexOf(String, int)` to find each occurrence  of the pattern you're looking for in the source string.  Just make sure to increment the index you find it at, so that you don't keep finding the same one.

Using this method

```
public static int count(String source, String lookFor) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = -1;

    while (i != 0) {
        i = source.indexOf(lookFor, i) + 1;
        if (i != 0) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I get this output when testing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(count("XLXXXLXX", "XX"));    // 3
    System.out.println(count("XXX", "XX"));         // 2
    System.out.println(count("X", "XX"));           // 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way that is most readable for me:

```
public static int countOccurrences(String string, String sub) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = string.indexOf(sub);
    while (i >= 0) {
        ++count;
        i = string.indexOf(sub, i+1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static int count(String s, String f) {
    int count = 0;
    int end = s.length() - f.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= end; ++i)
        if (s.startsWith(f, i))
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does this code help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "XLXXXLXX";
        int fromIndex = -1;
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            fromIndex = myString.indexOf("XX", fromIndex + 1);
            if (fromIndex != -1) {
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend String `substring(<str>, index)` approach as it's easier on the eyes.

If you want to try with more basic code to understand what's happening under hood, here is a character array approach.

```
private static int count(String givenStr, String overlappingStr) {

    char[] first = givenStr.toCharArray();
    char[] second = overlappingStr.toCharArray();

    int matchCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {

        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0, index = i; j < second.length && index < first.length; j++, index++) {

            if (first[index] == second[j]) {
                count++;
            } else if (first[index] != second[j] && count > 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count == second.length) {
            matchCount++;
        }
    }
    return matchCount;
}
```